# Build a machine learning model with text and numeric columns

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Studying machine learning I only faced problems with numeric and/or categorical columns to perform the predictions and train/test the algorithm. However, I got a data set with the product description column.

My doubt is how could be possible to take into account this column to predict how good the product is. For example, the target column is a numeric number from 0-10.

[image: Example of the data set with text column description]

Comment: So, if I post the code that I wrote here, will you change your mind ? All the discussions must start from a initial point. I totally disagree with your behavior, BUT it is my personal opinion.

Comment: It's not about the existence of code, it is about the nature of the question: if it is code-related, it belongs here; if not, it is not - there are other SE sites where this *may* be on-topic. Indeed all discussions must have a starting point, but please notice that SO is *not* a discussion forum.

Comment: I did not read any code in your "IBM Bluemix" question. Are you sure that even you are following the rules ?

Comment: Please read more carefully: I have already explicitly said that *it's not about the existence of code or not*.

Comment: The rules have changed since 2016. If you see questions which do not meet today's quality standards, please feel free to nominate them for closing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use bag of words model for the description column, after that you can use an algorithm which can predict a numeric result. For example: logistic regression.

We assume there are 2 rows of data. The rows are:

```
productid, description, grade:
3534, text about apple, 7.5
3535, text about phone, 9.3
```

Implement bag of words model to those rows:

```
productid, text, about, apple, phone, grade:
3534, 1, 1, 1, 0, 7.5
3535, 1, 1, 0, 1, 9.3
```

Now you can use this shape of data for logistic regression or for another algorithm.
If you don't know the bag of words model for text data, it is easy to understand with researching on Google. But of course there will be a lot of unnecessary words like "is" "the" etc.. Or punctuations like ".", ",", "!" etc.. If you apply some of Natural Language Processing techniques to your description column, your model's accuracy will rise a lot.